# Convert JSON String to Datatable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

see my script. why no data is displayed?
I try many thing here https://datatables.net/manual/ajax#Data-array-location but i need help to display my json data to the datatable

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var json = '{"company_id":"1","company_name":"schneider"}';

    $('#example').DataTable( {
     "data": JSON.parse(json),
        "columns": [
            { "data": "company_id" },
   { "data": "company_name"}
        ]
    } );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>C_ID</th>
   <th>C_NAME</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data parameter accepts an array not an individual object.

You JSON should look like this:

```
var json = '[{"company_id":"1","company_name":"schneider"}]';
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/or6p52gf/)

Comment: thanks this id what i do now
`var myarr = Array();
myarr.push(JSON.parse(json));

    $('#example').DataTable( {
     "data": myarr,`